# Config php via parse.com through composer

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have tried to install php via composer and without composer in Parse. Guide for install php through paser.I followed the steps and procedure but its not working please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you see? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `autoload.php` file included in the source code to include the SDK files easily. You can also [use this tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/05/parse-com-using-the-official-parse-php-sdk-v1-0-x/) to help you get started with the Parse PHP SDK without using Compose.

You need to do something like:

```
// include Parse SDK autoloader
require_once( 'autoload.php' );

// Add the "use" declarations where you'll be using the classes
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;

// Init parse: app_id, rest_key, master_key
ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');
```

Answer (score 1):

The part you may be struggling with is installing the composer using this command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Then 'ls' to see is you have a vendor directory.
Let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Composer. [Download Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
2. Create new Project.
3. Create **composer.json** file with dependencies like

   `{
       "require" : {
           "parse/php-sdk":"1.1.*"
       }
   }`
4. In the project folder open cmd and run the command `composer install` after that follow the parse [quick start](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/php) guide.

It works in my case.